# How to create resource group in Azure when you are working with multiple tenant IDs?

Tags: azure, terraform, terraform-provider-azure

The issue is that I have 2 tenant ids (D and V) and 2 subscriptions id (D and V) because I'am working for 2 different clients.

This cmd is for changing the tenant ID

```
az login --tenant <myTenantID>
```

And this cmd is for changing the subscription id

```
az login --subscription <mysubscriptionID>
```

currently I am working on V subscription/tenant id and I want to switch to D subscription/tenant id.

I have run these commands mentioned above, a browser page opens and i can log in.
But when I run my **terraform** command init, plan and apply. The terraform code creates the new **resource group** in the V subscription/tenant id and not in the D subscription/tenant id where I want.

Btw currently my default account is D but still it creates in the V account.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can customize your `azurerm` terraform provider as per your requirements by passing the relative argument.

### Terraform Code

###### Single Directory Structure (Depends on you but not recommended from my POV)

If you want to manage both tenants from a single directory, with only one `providers.tf` then you have to also use the `alias` feature of terraform providers.

- **providers.tf**

```
terraform {
  required_providers {
    azurerm = {
      source  = "hashicorp/azurerm"
      version = "~> 3.37.0"
    }
  }
}

provider "azurerm" {
  alias = "tenant_D_sub_D"
  features {}
  tenant_id       = "tenant_D_id"
  subscription_id = "subscription_D_id"
}

provider "azurerm" {
  alias = "tenant_V_sub_V"
  features {}
  tenant_id       = "tenant_V_id"
  subscription_id = "subscription_V_id"
}
```

- **resource_groups.tf**

```
## Create respective variables[name,location] definitions in your variables.tf 
resource "azurerm_resource_group" "stackoverflow_D" {
  provider = azurerm.tenant_D_sub_D

  name     = var.name
  location = var.location
}

resource "azurerm_resource_group" "stackoverflow_V" {
  provider = azurerm.tenant_V_sub_V

  name     = var.name
  location = var.location
}
```

##### Per-tenant-directory structure

- **Directory Tree**

```bash
.
├── tenant1
│   ├── sub1
│   │   └── providers.tf
│   └── sub2
│       └── providers.tf
└── tenant2
    ├── sub1
    │   └── providers.tf
    └── sub2
        └── providers.tf
```

- **providers.tf in any Sub**

```
terraform {
  required_providers {
    azurerm = {
      source  = "hashicorp/azurerm"
      version = "~> 3.37.0"
    }
  }
}

provider "azurerm" {
  features {}
  tenant_id       = "respective_tenant_id"
  subscription_id = "respective_subscription_id"
}
```

Technically you can remove these `tenant_id` and `subscription_id` arguments from here but you have to make sure via `az cli` or environment variables that the correct tenant and subscription id are selected.
Similar `providers.tf` file can be used for other subscriptions.

- **resource_group.tf**

```
## Create respective variables[name,location] definitions in your variables.tf
resource "azurerm_resource_group" "stackoverflow" {

  name     = var.name
  location = var.location
}
```

This will simplify your configurations and reduce maintenance efforts by a ton.

### Important Considerations

- Please note that the service principal/user should have permission on both tenants as well as subscriptions while making deployments either via a single directory or per-tenant-directory structure.

### Documentation URLs

- refer to this [azurerm-terraform-provider official documentation](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/azurerm/latest/docs#argument-reference) for more options.
- refer to [alias-multiple-provider-configurations](https://developer.hashicorp.com/terraform/language/providers/configuration#alias-multiple-provider-configurations) terraform documentation.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need the `az account` commands.

You can list your accounts as below (table for easier reading of the information)

```
az account list --output table
```

You can query which one is currently your default account using the query flag.

```
az account list --query "[?isDefault]"
```

Finally, you can change your account using either of the below commands using the subscription name or subscription Id from the command run earlier to list your subscriptions / accounts.

```
az account set --subscription "<YOUR SUBSCRIPTION NAME>"
az account set --subscription "<YOUR SUBSCRIPTION ID>"
```

Comment: thank you very much for your kind help. I ran this command 
az account set --subscription "<YOUR SUBSCRIPTION ID>" but it still creates in the V account and not in the D account

Comment: I did have some env variables (subscription id, tenant id, client id and secret) for the V account and I have also removed them in case it picks all ids from there. But still no luck.

Comment: Did you confirm your default subscription with the `az account list --query "[?isDefault]"` command's output?

Comment: strange thing is that my default one is D but it still creates resources group in V account. 
Yes I ran all commands as I mentioned above

Comment: Okay sorry I am just probably shooting in the dark. I had similar issues when I was creating resource group via Bicep. If your issue is specific to resource group creation, one more try I would do is to specify the subscription explicitly in the command (if you have not tried that earlier)
`az group create --location LOCATION --name GROUP_NAME --subscription SUBSCRIPTION_NAME (or ID)`

Comment: actually I want to create the resource group through terraform. Through cli I don't have any issue. Through cli I can create resource group but I want to create through terrraform because I want to create a github action.

Comment: Oh I am sorry I didn't realize you mentioned Terraform. I have no experience with Terraform so I am not sure I can add any further inputs on this. Just at all if it helps, I used Bicep and had used the command `az deployment sub create` and specified `targetScope` as `subscription` in the Bicep template.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/251324/discussion-between-bizimunda-and-gopal).